# Failed to send invitation email with devise_invitable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my app to heroku recently. When i try to send out an invite to anyone i get the following error.

```
 ActionView::Template:Error (invalid type sequence in UTF-8)
```

In my template I added `<%# encoding: utf-8 %>`.

I am stuck at the moment since it was working well in development enviroment

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `magic_encoding` from the command line? You might have missed a Controller that needs the `#encoding utf-8`. Can you show us some code?  Are you using any characters (Japanese, etc.) in your Controller?